# Gaussian Elimination without partial pivoting

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numerical-analysis

Good evening all,

```
a=[[1, 2, -1], [-2, 4, 1], [2, 2, 3]]

b=[-4,6, 1]

n=3

def SPP(): 

    for i in range(1,n):
        s=[0]*3
        p=[0]*3
        for j in range(1,n): 
            s[i]+=max(s[i], abs(a[i][j]))
        p[i]=i
    for k in range(1,n-1):
        rm=0
        for i in range(k,n): 
            r=abs(a[p[i]][k]/s[p[i]])
            if r>rm:
                rm=r
                j=1
            else:
                pass
        temp=p[k]
        p[k]=p[j]
        p[j]=temp
        for i in range(k+1,n): 
            a[p[i]][j]=a[p[i]][k]/a[p[k]][k]
            for j in range(k+1,n):
                a[p[i]][j]=a[p[i]][j]-a[p[i]][k]*a[p[k]][j]
    for k in range (1,n-1):
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            b[p[i]]=b[p[i]]-a[p[i]][k]*b[p[k]]
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        s=b[p[i]]
        x=s/a[p[i]]
        for j in range(i+1,n): 
            s=s-a[p[i]][j]*x[j]
```

I was working on a Gaussian Elimination scaled partial pivoting problem in Python, and I was following the format given in class, for most of the code above, but the only thing I am not entirely sure about is how do I get around dividing by zero? The directions weren't really clear, so I tried to put in an empty list, but I still got the following error.

---

ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 SPP()

in SPP()

```
---> 14             r=abs(a[p[i]][k]/s[p[i]])
     15             if r>rm:
     16                 rm=r
```

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried surrounding the error part with try... except block.

Comment: I just tried that, but there is still the issue with needing a value for r in the next line. I know that I am supposed to edit how I calculate s in line 6 (and probably how I calculate p in the next line), but I am not sure how I am supposed to do so.